# Regular expression in boost to extract information

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, boost

I want to macth the following expression using regular expression.

```
Execute stmtname
and
Execute stmtname using @a,@b;
```

and i want to extract stmtname and list of variables.
I have tried the following.

```
^execute[\s\t]+(\w+)[\s\t]+(using[\s\t]*(.+))?
```

but able to only parse the second statement only.
do anybody help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably not try to "parse" a grammar with regular expressions. Since you're already using Boost, why not venture into parser-generator country with Boost Spirit?

```
std::string statement_name;
std::vector<std::string> parameters;

bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
    first, last,
    qi::no_case[ 
        sr::distinct(qi::graph) ["execute"] 
        >> ident_ 
        >> -(sr::distinct(qi::graph) ["using"] >> 
                ('@' >> ident_) % ','
            )
        >> -qi::lit(';') >> qi::eoi
    ],
    qi::space,
    statement_name,
    parameters
);
```

The bulk of the complexity there is only because I tried to be very meticulous with

- delimited identifier token (so that e.g. `execute_only` would not parse as `execute _only`), and
- accepting whitespace
- accepting optional `;` at the end (your examples are conflicting in this regard)

A test program prints:

```
-----------------------------------------
Parsing 'Execute no_parameter_statement'
Parse success
statement_name: no_parameter_statement
0 parameters:
-----------------------------------------
Parsing 'Execute stmtname using @a,@b;'
Parse success
statement_name: stmtname
2 parameters:
    @a
    @b
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b53dd767dd4eec70)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace sr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
qi::rule<It, std::string()> ident_ = sr::distinct(qi::char_("a-z0-9_")) [ qi::alpha >> *(qi::char_("a-z0-9_")) ];

int main() {
    for(std::string const input : {
            "Execute no_parameter_statement",
            "Execute stmtname using @a,@b;"
            })
    {
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing '" << input << "'\n";

        std::string statement_name;
        std::vector<std::string> parameters;

        auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,qi::no_case[ 
                sr::distinct(qi::graph) ["execute"] 
                >> ident_ 
                >> -(sr::distinct(qi::graph) ["using"] >> 
                        ('@' >> ident_) % ','
                    )
                >> -qi::lit(';') >> qi::eoi
            ],
            qi::space,
            statement_name,
            parameters
        );

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parse success\n";

            std::cout << "statement_name: " << statement_name << "\n";
            std::cout << parameters.size() << " parameters:\n";
            for(auto const& p : parameters)
                std::cout << "\t@" << p << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n"; 
        }

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea of using boost spirit. I was thinking about to use this concept so studying this concept. again thanks for sharing the code it is working well.